# Is it possible to run a Node script from a web page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

I'am searching for days now but could not get an answer.
I would like to do the following:

1. User connects to editor.html (Apache2 with basic http auth)
2. User want to open a file (lets say /home/user1/myfile.txt) on the server with his user/pass (same as in passwd)
3. Node.js Script gets startet with user rights from above and user can edit file

The Node Script will handle the connection via websockets and read/writes files.

I think the biggest problem is that its not possible to run a node script on the server from a web page... and I don´t want to involve any php/cgi scripts... only Apache and Node.js / JS.

Please also comment or answer if you know that it is really not possible...

Thanks!

Kodak

Edit: The workflow should be the following:
User access webpage -> enters his credential (same as in passwd) -> node.js script gets started with the user rights of the logged in user -> files getting read or written with user rights

Biggest Problem: who starts the Node.js script? Apache? How?

Comment: WebSockets (or plain AJAX) can do that easily.  Look at Socket.io.

Comment: letting your users start an arbitrary process on your server is the best way to make sure you have a backdoor into your system. Don't do this, and instead please describe what you actually want to achieve by letting your users do this.

Comment: apache can proxy to nodejs.  Instead of command line script, write your nodejs program as a simple web app using http auth.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It should run on a local server and I want an Editor so that the users can edit their files on the server without ssh, just the browser. And I just want to use apache  and node.js. The node server should not run at the beginning. I want to start it with user rights when the user logs in. I know there is suEXEC for Apache but it cannot run a node script by default as far as I know...

Comment: No, *what* are they editing that they should be able to run those things as scripts on the server?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans they are editing real files on the server. Every user has a home directoy on the server (linux) and they should be able to edit their files on the server with their rights... I could run a node script with user myuser1 and it would read-write files. But then I would not work when user myuser2 tries to read write his files in /home/myuser2...

Comment: okay, that still doesn't answer the question. You're talking about users editing files that "then run on the server". What kind of files are they editing that require that "running" part. Because for most purposes you just have an editor app running that requests the file listing, or actual file content, acts as an editor in the browser, and then when you hit "Save", sends the data back to the server and the server updates it. Done. You're making it weird by talking about files that need to run without explaining what those files are and why the conventional approach is not good enough

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yeah, its the editor app (server, read/write files, sends data to user via web sockets) that is made with Node.js and this app I want to run. One App. Different users. Imagine you whould start the node server(editor server) with the user "nodeuser". Then a user myuser1 connects to the app/node server and saves a file. With which user rights (user/group) will the file be written on the server? I would say user: nodeuser / group: nodeuser. But i want it to be myuser1/myuser1. And when myuser2 connects it should be myuser2/myuser2... nothing more.

Comment: if it's a client-server setup, I would care about file permission settings, not user/group settings. Make the files visible to the users that should see them, and given them the correct octal permission code, done. User myuser1 should not be able to see content from the muser2 dir, and vice versa, but logging in to your webapp is NOT logging in to the machine. You probably shouldn't deep-link file ownership and user accounts this way. Just make the webapp expose only permitted content, done.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I know its not common but its a stupid requirement...

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to start a separate node instance for every user? In my opinion you should really re-think this  part. I haven't tested it but I guess running 1-10 node instances on a single server would work without problems, however imagine you have 100+ users. That would be a huge load on your server. Even if it's not common it doesn't really make sense and speaks against what a server actually is. It would be like to start a separate web server for every user. I'm sure if you really need to limit the user access rights with filesystem permissions there's a better way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate to be this person, but...

That is not the way node is designed, it is designed to use the event loop, I would recommend having node serve the static files, maybe using apache as a proxy, then when someone requests a certain page, doing what ever needs to be done, if you really must spawn a child process, use `child_process.spawn`, as for the rights of the user, I recommend just passing in a code, like 1=admin, 2=user, 3=guest, and the child process can do what is needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use Socket.io - [Official Socket.IO Website](http://socket.io/)

You can also use Express with socket IO to create a separate app server. - [Express JS Website](http://expressjs.com/)

You may want to consider security implications of allowing a user to connect directly using their server side account. There are also many applications available that already do this that you might consider implementing instead of writing your own, with all the properly embedded security that will be required.

Comment: My Problem is that I dont want to run a Node Server at the beginning. I also dont want to run the Node Server as root and the chroot to the user when they connect. The user should login on a webpage and then see the editor... on the server side, when the user logs in, the Node.js server gets startet with the logged in user. That ensures that the user can only edit his own files... I just dont know how I can start the server when the user logs in because something needs to start the Node server....

Comment: Could you explain why you dont want to run the node at the beginning, or why you cant use php. 
You can ensure that users can edit only their files by creating a folder with their username+id, and checking before request, that user is authenticated and is trying to access a file which path contains that users's name and id + some prefix perhaps. ie
user "john_smith" could only access files that are in :

/homes/sites/private/john_smith_439/file.txt

All users would first go through database authentication and from there you can create/add extra permissions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let your users GET static auth.html page (via apache) without any authentication.

Let form submit action is some auth.js (Node.js script). This auth.js check if user's authentication is success. If so it starts node.js server, setups socket.io on it and  redirects user to some editor.html.

In this case as you can notice that there is an authentication based on node.js scripting. If you want basic apache2 one I can recommend you the next scenario:

There is auth.html and editor.html pages on the server. Last one placed in `/private` folder and direct access to this folder is denied by .htaccess. So when the user pass apache2 authentication in auth.html he GET this auth.html which is empty document with `onload` event handler that send AJAX to auth.js (Node.js script). Node.js get `private/editor.html` and send it to user like `/editor.html`.

In this case user never has an access to editor without passing authentication. And after authentication node.js server is started and socket.io is setup and everything fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will evaluate that this weekend and report back!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

It is possible to write a custom authentication program for apache with mod-auth-external:
https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/

With basic authentication enabled the webserver would pass the credentials to a script/program and this can then run the node app.

Comment: pwauth (https://code.google.com/p/pwauth/) can authenticate against the passwd. I ended up changing the sourcecode to my needs...