# Can you run a node.js code on java script

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, discord.js

I have a js code, basically a discord bot code, so usually need to do to run this bot is open cmd in the js path and do `node {file_name}.js`, so now suppose I have a java script code that I wish to run on button click and send a message box when it starts running, how would I do that. This is my JS Code

```js
const Discord=require("discord.js"),
client=new Discord.Client;
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)});

client.on("message", e => {
"ping" === e.content && e.reply("Pong!");
});

client.login("token");
```

Also if possible would like to have the code in the application code itself, something like this

```cs
string code = "const Discord=require("discord.js"),
client=new Discord.Client;
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)});

client.on("message", e => {
"ping" === e.content && e.reply("Pong!");
});

client.login("token");";
```

Answers are appreciated, thank you for reading :) Have a good day

Answer (score -1):

I think you will be able to have the answer here: [Is it possible to run a Node script from a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687604/is-it-possible-to-run-a-node-script-from-a-web-page)

The best way I suppose is to call an express server and this one will call your node script.

Hope this will help ;)